# How to sum up row numbers in Excel conditioned by a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a formula I can use that sums up the numbers in columns F and G provided that value in column A is ... "A", for example

I attempted to be explicit about it by saying `=SUMIF(F8:G11,A8:A11="A")` ) Sum up stuff in F-G column A has a value of "A"

This doesn't work. What am I missing please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One the order of SUMIF is: `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])`

Two.  The sum_range must be the same shape as the range.

We can add two together:

```
=SUMIF(A8:A11,"A",F8:F11)+SUMIF(A8:A11,"A",G8:G11)
```

[image]

Or if you are okay with a little volatility we can use OFFSET and wrap in sumproduct:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A8:A11,"A",OFFSET(F8:F11,,{0,1})))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B7`:

```
=SUM(FILTER(F1:G4,A1:A4="A"))
```

Or;

```
=SUM((A1:A4="A")*(F1:G4))
```

I guess the latter can be used with `SUMPRODUCT()` in older version.